# "Record" a cell value in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Suppose I set a random number in cell A1, rolling 1,2,3,4,5,6 every 5 minutes

If number 6 has rolled, I would like to print "congratulations!" in cell B1, and stay there permanently (until I reset it)

Say, it rolled 6 after 20 minutes in cell A1, it prints "congratulations!" cell B1, then after 5 minutes, value in cell A1 changes to 3, but "congratulations!" stays in cell B1

Is there a simple function or script to do this? And how can I reset it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Set a Time-Driven trigger to run setRandom every 5 minutes. This sets a random number in A1 and checks if A1=6 and B1 is blank. If true it sets B1 to "congratulations!". It also creates a custom menu named Reset which runs reset to blank out B1.

```
function onOpen(){
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu(
    'Reset', [ 
      { name: 'Reset', functionName: 'reset' },
      ]);  
}
function setRandom() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
 var cell=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1  //Generate random number between 1 and 6 (6 is max and 1 is min)
     s.getRange("A1") .setValue(cell)  //Set A1 to random mumber  
var val= s.getRange("B1").getValue() // Get B1 value
  if(cell==6 && val==''){ // If Random Number is 6 and B1 is blank set B1 to "congratulations!"
      s.getRange("B1").setValue("congratulations!")
  }
  else{return}
 }  
 function reset(){     
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")    
 var val= s.getRange("B1").setValue('')
      }
```